# Changing button text everytime when button was clicked in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have button as AjaxLink and label inside. And I would like to implement toggle button to change text everytime when it was clicked. So let's say button has initial text "**One**", after click it should be "**Two**" and after another next click it should be "**One**" again and so on.

```html
<a wicket:id="myBtn" type="button">
    <span wicket:id="btnText"></span>
</a>
```

```java
AjaxLink<Void> myBtn = new AjaxLink<>("myBtn") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        someModel.toggle();
    }
};
Label btnText = new Label("btnText", someModel.map(on -> on ? "One" : "Two"));
btnText.setOutputMarkupId(true);
btnText.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
myBtn.add(btnText);
add(myBtn);
```

My label doesnt re-render after click happened, how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `target.add(btnText)` in `onClick()`:

```
final Label btnText = new Label("btnText", someModel.map(on -> on ? "One" : "Two"));
btnText.setOutputMarkupId(true);    
AjaxLink<Void> myBtn = new AjaxLink<>("myBtn") {
   @Override
   public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
     someModel.toggle();
     target.add(btnText);
   }
};
myBtn.add(btnText);
add(myBtn);
```